# Как изменить адрес основного шлюза

Tags: windows, сеть

Как изменить адрес основного шлюза с помощью командной строки?
Допустим у меня сейчас адрес основного шлюза: 
192.168.1.1
я хочу изменить его на 192.168.0.1

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/958143/505198 оно?

Comment: Тут ещё и ип адрес надо сменить

Answer (score 0):

```
route delete 0.0.0.0
route add 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 192.168.0.1
```